Token validation based on JWKS is not being executed
I am facing an issue with JWT bearer authentication in an .NET 8 application, we cannot use the .well-known endpoint from the identity provider to get the JWKS uri, since we use custom JWTs. So I tried to implement the JWKS resolving but that to does not seem to work:
Using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package (8.0.7).
Inside the program.cs added the following code to add the authentication logic to an API:
var jwksText = File.ReadAllText(certificatePath);
var keyset = new JsonWebKeySet(jwksText);
var selectedKey = keyset[0];

builder.Services
     .AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtBearerScheme)
     .AddJwtBearer(AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtBearerScheme, configureOptions =>
     {
           configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
           configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[] {"https://my-nice-issuer"};
           configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = true;
           configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters.RequireSignedTokens = true;
           configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = selectedKey;
     });

and using:
[...]
builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
[...]

For the controller we use the Authorization attribute, but when hitting the method which should be authorized, the authorization logic from the .NET library is not being hit:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtBearerScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData() 
{
    [...]
}


Which logic is not hit? What do you get from this request? Unauthorized?

Nothing at all, it just is passing into the controller.

The request is being processed as if there was no authentication, when I set a breakpoint inside the controller method, it will be hit.
